# Is there a way to convince the compiler that a @NonNull variable is actually Nullable in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, nullable

In Android, there is a `android.location.LocationListener` class, and the Android Operating System updates locations using the class as below:

[image: android.location.LocationListener]

It says that Location is @NonNull, but in reality the OS does return null sometimes, which crashes the app.

```
object : LocationListener {
    override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
        doSomethingWithLocation(location) // App crashes here, because location is null
    }
}
```

Is there some way to tell the compiler that `Location` is actually `Location?` ?

Comment: why don't just declare it nullable then? ```override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location?)```

Comment: I've never received a null location for this case. Are you sure that the code that's using the location is correct?

Comment: Trying to change the function signature by declaring it nullable isn't allowed by the compiler.

Yes I am sure it is correct, this only happens on very old devices running very old android versions.

Comment: so why can't you use a null-safe call?

Comment: My question is whether or not there is a way to convince the compiler that the NonNull value is actually nullable. Using a null-safe call does not convince the compiler that the NonNull value is actually nullable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two workarounds for this.

First, if the interface contains only a single abstract method, we can use SAM conversion and override the type of the parameter to `Location?` like this:

```kotlin
val listener = LocationListener { location: Location? ->
    doSomethingWithLocation(location)
}
```

What is interesting, we can override the parameter if using SAM conversion, but we can't if using full syntax of subtyping. It seems `LocationListener` is SAM, so this solution could work in your case.

If the first solution is not possible, we can override the interface in Java:

```java
public interface MyLocationListener extends LocationListener {
    @Override
    void onLocationChanged(@Nullable Location location);
}
```

```kotlin
val listener = object : MyLocationListener {
    override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location?) {
        doSomethingWithLocation(location)
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case the SAM conversion isn't possible, but using Java to change the Nullable method signature does the trick.

I wish there was a way to force this in Kotlin, but your solution works, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is way to discard the nullability information coming from java. in your case this is a problem because as pointed out by @RobCo, kotlin will automatically insert non-null assertion for location and the assertion will fail.

So it seems the only solution you are left with is to use a java wrapper type which will only provide you with non-null location values, which you can use in your kotlin code. this wrapper could look like

```
import androidx.core.util.Consumer;

public class LocationHandler{
    LocationHandler(Consumer<Location> delegate){
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    private Consumer<Location> delegate;

    private LocationListener _listener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
            // Only forward non-null location values
            if(location != null){ delegate.accept(location); }
            else {
                Log.d("LocationHandler", "Received null Location");
            }
        }
    };

    public LocationListener getListener(){
        return _listener;
    }
}
```

Now in your kotlin code you can use it as

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val locationDelegate = Consumer<Location> {
        // Do something with non-null location
    }
    
    override fun somFun {
        val locationHandler = LocationHandler(locationDelegate)
        val locMan = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
        locMan.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
                0L, 
                0F, 
                locationHandler.listener)
    }
}
```

Comment: The compiler thinks this is a mistake and this does not answer my question.

Comment: That warning is valid for compiler's prespective, since you are using null safe call with a non-nullable type. but you don't have any choice either use `location: Location?` or use a null safe call with warning

Comment: I agree with @mightyWOZ -  i don't understand the reason behind downvote, but this is the correct way to make it null-safe, if java api is throwing nullable object, even though if its marked as non-nullable.

Comment: You can write a quick test-case and check how its behaving.

Comment: This might not work though as Kotlin normally adds a `Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull` call which would still cause a crash. There is a compiler flag (`-Xno-param-assertions`) to disabled this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I think assertions should not be disabled. instead a java wrapper type can be introduced to filter out the null values. I will update the answer.